# How can UICollectionViewCells have different spacing

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, tvos

Good morning, I faced a problem, I have to let UICollectionViewCells in a UICollectionView have different spacing, my cells have different width but the same height and only one row. UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout can only set min spacing while I want every cell has a different spacing.It looks like this:

--------   20   ------- 10 -----5---

How can I resolve this?
Thank you!

Comment: How do you know what spacing to use between cells?

Comment: This article might be helpful: https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/collection-view-layouts/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make the cell have the same space . Then make the cell width different and make space in the cell.

Comment: thank you, I know this is a way to be, but this is an app on AppleTV, it has a focus ,when a cell becomes focused, the cell will be center in X, so  if I set the cell width, the content may not be visible.

Comment: If your question is about Apple TV / tvOS, you should tag it with `tvos`. I've fixed your tags for you this time.

Comment: i'm so sorry, this drives me so crazy and thank you very much.

Comment: There is another way. Make a kind of cell as space cell and do not responce to any event.